# How to iterate tabs and list boxes within them

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I have a WPF application that is used to select tests that are later run as part of an automated testing application.

In the UI I have multiple tab controls that represent each of the test categories. Inside each tab is a listbox of checkboxes for each test.

When the user selects all of their tests and clicks the run button, I need to iterate over each of tabs and the listboxes within them to build the final test list. I don't want to have tons of statements that are along the lines of:

```
GetTab1Tests();
GetTab2Tests();
GetTab3Tests();
// Continue
```

I would like to design this in a way that I can say:

```
foreach(Tab t in tabControl)
{
    CollectTestsFromListbox(**listbox associated with t**);
}
```

How can I bind this information? My best guess is to create a dictionary that pairs tabs with the necessary listbox, but is that good practice moving forward? As the application being tested grows, the need for more tabs may grow as well.

**EDIT**
At the moment I have tried setting the DataContext of the tab:

```
<TabItem x:name="tabLoginTests DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstboxLoginTests}">
```

And in the .xaml.cs file I can call:

```
tabLoginTests.DataContext
```

All this does is return `{System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:4}`. I can't figure out how to take this object and grab the listbox control itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to bind any properties, I would just like a way to relate them, so that at the application level I can reference the listbox depending on which tab I have.

Comment: @HighCore 's suggestion implies that you should be following MVVM.  Doing so--which is the proper model for WPF applications--would allow you get all the tests, and run them with one LINQ statement.

Comment: @NETscape Thanks. I have repeated this over and over countless times in SO, that I simply don't feel like keep saying it anymore.

Comment: Also, along with my previous comment, with MVVM you would have a `AppVM` which has collection of `CategoryVM`, where each `CategoryVM` would have a collection of `TestVM`, where each `TestVM` would derive from `BaseTestVM`, and each `BaseTestVM` would have a `IsSelected` property bound to the checkbox's `Checked` property; or something to that effect.

Comment: @HighCore we miss you in chat ;) and that's probably for obvious reasons, but OP, feel free to join [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) if you need help after you learn what MVVM is.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestion. I've done a bit of reading, but I have a long way to go. I edited the question to include something I have tried. If you don't mind, can you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: You could do it with dictionary OR if you know that you are gonna add the listbox as the first elemnt (or second or whatever) everytime you could do it like this  **CollectTestsFromListbox((ListBox)t.Controls[0]);**

Comment: @vajura is it possible to use a lambda statement, if I know the id of the control?

Comment: @McAdam331 Yes you just need to cast it as a ListBox, **((ListBox)t.Controls[0]).Add("string");**

Comment: @Vajura Thanks. I was able to figure it out by using `((Grid)tabLoginTests.Content).Children.OfType<ListBox>().Where(lb => (lb.Name == "lstboxLoginTests")).FirstOrDefault();` To get the listbox. I also found the way to use it via the data context - I had to cast it using `as` like this: `tabLoginTests.DataContext as ListBox`. If you can formulate your comment into an answer, it's all yours. You deserve it.

Comment: @McAdam331 nah you did all of the work i just pointed you in the right direction :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I was able to use still involved using the data context. At first, I was unable to cast the object to a list box implicitly, but realized eventually that it was possible using `as`.

```
var loginListBox = tabLoginTests.DataContext as ListBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the ListBox to the Tag property of the intended TabControl object as you create the ListBox.

You will then be able to access it with t.Tag .  You may then cast it to a ListBox (.Tag is an Object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple ItemsControl with binding to a model.

To access selected tests just iterate over lists using Groups property.

```
public IEnumerable<Test> GetSelectedTests()
{
    return Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Tabs).SelectMany(x => x.Tests).Where(x => x.IsEnabled);
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="640">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4"/>
                    <TabControl Width="300" MinHeight="250" Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    </TabControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
            Groups.Add(new Group()
            {
                Name = "Group1",
                Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>()
                {
                    new Tab()
                    {
                        Name = "Tab11",
                        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>()
                        {
                            new Test() { Name = "Test111", IsEnabled = true },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test112", IsEnabled = false }
                        }
                    },
                    new Tab()
                    {
                        Name = "Tab12",
                        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>()
                        {
                            new Test() { Name = "Test121", IsEnabled = true },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test122", IsEnabled = false },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test123", IsEnabled = false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Groups.Add(new Group()
            {
                Name = "Group2",
                Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>()
                {
                    new Tab()
                    {
                        Name = "Tab21",
                        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>()
                        {
                            new Test() { Name = "Test211", IsEnabled = true },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test212", IsEnabled = false },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test213", IsEnabled = true }

                        }
                    },
                    new Tab()
                    {
                        Name = "Tab22",
                        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>()
                        {
                            new Test() { Name = "Test221", IsEnabled = true },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test222", IsEnabled = false },
                            new Test() { Name = "Test223", IsEnabled = false }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tab
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```